# What is a good output format for Java app input?

Tags: java, c, ipc

I currently need to resolve an issue with duplicated logic on web-based monitoring (Java) and a big legacy C server app.

For this I need to build new clients for the C app, but I have no idea what formats are good for Java to read.

Should I use XML, Json, or some other format?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized, since I think it is.

Comment: It's Java so you should use XML. Never miss a chance to make your data more bloated and ugly than it needs to be. That's the whole point of Java. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **completely dependent on your problem domain**.  Java has libraries available for reading XML, JSON and a host of other protocols.

You need to be asking questions like:

- How much data will I be producing?
- Does the data need to be human-readable?
- Is storage size an issue?
- Is the time to read / write the data an issue?
- Do I need to support multiple, versioned protocols?

Comment: That's kind of why I asked about a format, not a protocol. The protocol actually stays as it is (there are just some additions and minor semantic changes).

Comment: I've used the words protocol and format interchangeably but I am talking about the data format in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either, JSON is the new standard for web-based messages and there are plenty of Java libraries to handle JSON efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one stop perfect fit here, but maybe Google's [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is a good idea?

There's a native C++ compiler, which is probably of no use to you; there's an active [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) implementation that you might be able to use, though.